# RealmSwift display for each date to tableview section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I'm new in swift and realm.

I want to display data which are stored in realm.

I want to display for each date to tableview section.

Item Object

```
class Item: Object {
    @objc dynamic var amount: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var date: Date?
    var parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: Category.self, property: "items")
}
```

#### viewController

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class HistoryViewController: UITableViewController {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var items: Results<Item>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        items = realm.objects(Item.self)
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return items?.count ?? 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "represents a day"
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return "Item entries with the corresponding date"
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = amount
        return cell
    }

}
```

date stored

```
Optional(Results<Item> <0x7ff9ba460610> (
[0] Item {
    amount = 900;
    date = 2018-01-27 06:00:06 +0000;
},
[1] Item {
    amount = 9000;
    date = 2018-01-27 06:20:29 +0000;
},
[2] Item {
    amount = 400;
    date = 2018-01-28 06:22:32 +0000;
},
[3] Item {
    amount = 45;
    date = 2018-01-28 01:21:27 +0000;
},
[4] Item {
    amount = 258665;
    date = 2018-01-30 02:35:45 +0000;
}
```

))

I want to display like below

- 2018-01-27

  - 900
  - 9000
- 2018-01-28

  - 400
  - 45
- 2018-01-30

  - 258665

Comment: And what is your actual question? Are you trying to create a table view, where each section represents a day and each cell in that section represents an `Item` entry with the corresponding date? What have you tried so far for implementing this?

Comment: thanks for the comment. as you saying, I am trying to create table view.
I edited my question with more infomation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to make quite a few changes in order to group your tableview based on days to which the `date` property of `Item` corresponds.

First of all, you shouldn't store all items as a property of your class, since you won't be needing all items in one collection. Rather, the approach I suggest is to use an Array and a Dictionary as the data sources for your table view. The array will store the unique days (the `Date` objects in the array will correspond to midnight of the specific day) for which you have entries in `Realm`. The dictionary will contain the same days as its keys and the values will be of type `Results<Item>` for storing each `Item` whose `date` property is on the same day as the specific key.

I have tested below code in a playground and its working as expected.

```
class HistoryViewController: UITableViewController {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var groupedItems = [Date:Results<Item>]()
    var itemDates = [Date]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let items = realm.objects(Item.self)
        //Find each unique day for which an Item exists in your Realm
        itemDates = items.reduce(into: [Date](), { results, currentItem in
            let date = currentItem.date!
            let beginningOfDay = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: Calendar.current.component(.year, from: date), month: Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date), day: Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date), hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0))!
            let endOfDay = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: Calendar.current.component(.year, from: date), month: Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date), day: Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date), hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59))!
            //Only add the date if it doesn't exist in the array yet
            if !results.contains(where: { addedDate->Bool in
                return addedDate >= beginningOfDay && addedDate <= endOfDay
            }) {
                results.append(beginningOfDay)
            }
        })
        //Filter each Item in realm based on their date property and assign the results to the dictionary
        groupedItems = itemDates.reduce(into: [Date:Results<Item>](), { results, date in
            let beginningOfDay = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: Calendar.current.component(.year, from: date), month: Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date), day: Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date), hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0))!
            let endOfDay = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: Calendar.current.component(.year, from: date), month: Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date), day: Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date), hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59))!
            results[beginningOfDay] = realm.objects(Item.self).filter("date >= %@ AND date <= %@", beginningOfDay, endOfDay)
        })
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return itemDates.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "represents a day"
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return groupedItems[itemDates[section]]!.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let itemsForDate = groupedItems[itemDates[indexPath.section]]!
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(Array(itemsForDate.sorted(byKeyPath: "date"))[indexPath.row].amount)"
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining in great detail. I was able to achieve my purpose.

Comment: Legend! It really works well except self.groupedMessages[self.itemDates[indexPath.section]]![indexPath.row]