# Getting sections by Date from Realm

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I've got a working `UITableView` sourced by this model in Realm:

```
@objcMembers class Transaction: Object {

    dynamic var account: Account!
    dynamic var picPath: String = ""
    dynamic var transAmount: Double = 0.00
    dynamic var transDate: Date!
    dynamic var note: String = ""

}
```

The relevant code in `TableViewDataSource` is:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    let accounts = realm.objects(Account.self)

    for item in accounts{
        if item.isCurrent{
            self.currentAccount = item
        }
    }
    let detailPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "account = %@", currentAccount)
    let transactions = realm.objects(Transaction.self).filter(detailPredicate)

    return transactions.count
}
```

Now, I'd like to organize the `tableView` a bit better by grouping it by individual dates, but I find myself thrashing around for a succinct approach. From my searches on Google and SO, it's either so common and easy that everyone already knows how, or it's never been tried before.

Specifically, I'm looking for a granularity defined by each individual calendar day as a section header, under which all `Transaction`s time-hacked within that day are listed in chronological order. Obviously, the information is there, but I seem not to be able to see the woods for the trees...

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Tip: You should not be getting your data in numberOfRows, you should be getting all of the data beforehand, preferably in viewDidLoad and constructing the data source by splitting them into rows and then using that data source for constructing the table view.

Comment: Good point, @RakeshaShastri! Let me look at that...

Comment: [RealmSwift display for each date to tableview section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48621128/realmswift-display-for-each-date-to-tableview-section/48630088#48630088) might help you

Comment: @DávidPásztor-- Required a bit of newbie head-scratching and tweaking to fit it into my existing code, but works perfectly! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@DávidPásztor's link to [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48621128/realmswift-display-for-each-date-to-tableview-section/48630088#48630088) worked perfectly, after the expected tweaks to fit my existing code.

Excellent!