# Group results of filtering by date without dumping everything to memory

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a list of `Documents` that are generated on multiple dates. I need to show a `UITableView` with the documents and each section has to be a different day.

I'm going to have several thousands of `Documents` saved on realm so I'm trying to find a way to group the `Documents` by `creationDate` without dumping the result of filtering the documents to memory.

Also it may happen that a new document is received so I would have to refresh the whole table and dump it to memory again just to add one document.

I couldn't find any way of doing this. I also think of paginating the results so I have an smaller list to "handle" in memory but Realm can't paginate either so I'm not sure how to proceed...

My `Document` looks like this:

```
final class Document: Object {

    @objc dynamic var createdByUserId: String?
    @objc dynamic var creationDate: Date?
    @objc dynamic var userId: String?
}
```

Comment: What about displaying (and querying) documents for a limited date period and then handling pagination yourself by querying for the next or previous date period as needed?

Comment: but this would still require to access the objects... which is what i want to avoid

Comment: In your second sentence you wrote you want to show the documents in a table view?

Comment: yes, but I would need to fetch from x date to x date and then access all the realm objects from disk to get the date and I would be losing the laziness from realm: "as Realm will only load objects from the results of the query once they are explicitly accessed"

Comment: You can certainly set up pagination based on the days - for example you could load day 1-5 and their children, then, as the user scrolls, load days 6-10 rinse repeat. Also, Realm objects are live updating so once a filter is in place, any objects matching that filter are automatically available in the current results. For example, if days 1-5 are showing and a user adds something to day #2. That object will in the current results. You just need to refresh your tableView with an observer. You can get as broad of fine-grained as needed at that point.

Comment: Have a look at [RealmSwift display for each date to tableview section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48621128/realmswift-display-for-each-date-to-tableview-section/48630088#48630088)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this before:

**Method 1 [Very slow but least maintenance]**:
During runtime, create an array containing unique startOfDay dates for all your creationDates of your Document Objects. Call this array DateGroups.

In every document object, add 'dateGroup' variable.

```
 final class Document: Object {
    @objc dynamic var createdByUserId: String?
    @objc dynamic var creationDate: Date?
    @objc dynamic var dateGroup: Date?
    @objc dynamic var userId: String?
 }
```

Now you can pull out objects from a specific dateGroup:

```
realm.objects(Document.self).filter("dateGroup = %@", Particular-Date-Group)
```

**Method 2 [Very fast but requires high maintenance]**:
You declare everything like in method 1. 
However, you have to create a Realm Object that maintains active dateGroups. Call it DateGroup and let it have only one variable called date or startOfDay.

Method 2 is faster than Method 1 but requires high maintenance because you have to keep track of when a dateGroup should be added or deleted

Comment: but I need to display all the dateGroup at the same time, all the sections at the same time... imagine that it's like a chat but instead of messages I have to show documents...

Comment: If you need to display all of them at the same time. You first ask realm for all the dateGroup objects available, then for each object you ask realm to get you all the Documents whose creationDate.startOfDay == DateGroupInQuestion or whose dateGroup == DateGroupInQuestion. Whichever approach you prefer